# Delphi Service Application TStringList LoadFromFile Memory Leak

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, tstringlist

Is there someone in there that can explain why my code causes a memory leakage of 4KB, looking on the TaskManager.  Delphi 2005, service application:

```
unit uMain;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, SvcMgr, Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls;

type
  TgwDebugService_s = class(TService)
    Timer1: TTimer;
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  gwDebugService_s: TgwDebugService_s;

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  gwDebugService_s.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TgwDebugService_s.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TgwDebugService_s.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  // Service is Fired
  while not Terminated do
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True);// wait for termination

end;

procedure TgwDebugService_s.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  // Service stops

end;

procedure TgwDebugService_s.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
var
  sl : TStringList;
begin
  Timer1.Enabled := False;
  Sleep(1000);

  sl := TStringList.Create;
  try
    //if FileExists( 'c:\OnlyOnMyPc\test.txt' ) then
    sl.LoadFromFile( 'c:\OnlyOnMyPc\test.txt' );  // remove this line and will be find
    sl.Add( 'Test @ ' + FormatDateTime( 'dd.mm.yyyy hh:mm:ss.z', Now ) );
    sl.SaveToFile( 'c:\OnlyOnMyPc\test.txt' );
  finally
    sl.Clear;
    FreeAndNil( sl );
  end;

  Timer1.Enabled := True;

end;

end.
```

Appreciate your time and your help.

Cheers.
gbp

Comment: I don't see any memory leaks in your code, task manager is not the appropriate tool for that, use FastMM in Full Debug Mode. There are a couple of improvement points though. a) don't implement ServiceExecute, it already does the same out of the box. b) don't use a TStringList to add a line to a file, remember that `LoadFromFile` reads the WHOLE file into memory, when the logfile grows larger, this code will become slower and slower (and a memory hog). Appending to a file with `TFileStream` would be more appropriate in your case.

Comment: And why do you have `Sleep()` inside your Timer event; it's blocking code, and one of the resons to use a Timer in the first place is to avoid that. Also, you don't need to call `sl.Clear` before destroying `sl`; the list is automatically cleared when you destroy it. Finally `FreeAndNil` is serious overkill for a local variable; `sl.Destroy` would be fine.

Comment: @Craig I think Free would be more normal than Destroy. So that you avoid having Free in some parts of the code (destructors) and Destroy in others (methods).

Comment: As @whosrdaddy already sad Task Manager isn't good tool for monitoring memory leaks. Why? Task Manager shows how much memoy did certain application been assigned, but that specific application could actually be using much less memory than that at that specific time.

Comment: @David I agree that `Free` would be more "normal", but I was making the point the `Destroy` would suffice. In a local var `Create; try Use; finally Free; end` pattern, the benefit of `Free` checking if the object is **nil** is unnecessary because `Create` will have assigned a value. There's no harm in using `Free`, but it's not necessary. Similarly, there's no harm in using `FreeAndNil`. I just consider it overkill, and wonder whether a developer doing so understands the differences.

Comment: @CraigYoung Obviously I know that too. But the comment you left did not say that. And the naive developer might start calling `Destroy` in destructors and that doesn't end well.

Comment: There is plenty misunderstanding about `Free`. Due in part to poor documentation. E.g. Current [docs](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.TObject.Free) still claim: "_if the object was never initialized, `Free` would not result in an error_" (Simply not true in the case of a local object variable.) Docs also advise against calling `Destroy` directly. This has lead to pretty terrible design decisions in my current job. Devs decided to "override" the **non-virtual** `Free` method on the basis that one should "always" call `Free` to destroy an object. (Imagine the problems....)

Comment: @CraigYoung The docs are very clear to that if you read the whole paragraph. Just before your cite you can read ***Free** automatically calls the destructor if the object reference is **not nil***. Do you think they should add a hint, that you have to remember the things said two sentences before? They did: *Free is successful even if the object is nil; if the object was never initialized, Free would not result in an error.*

Comment: @SirRufo The docs are only clear to someone who already understands the intricacies of memory initialisation. Regardless of the preamble; the quoted clause is drawn as a **false** _general_ conclusion precisely because local variables are **not initialised to nil**. The docs also fail to mention that calling `Free` twice on the same object (perhaps via different references) still leads to errors. (Not documentation errors, merely omissions. But still fall under the category of poor documentation.) The docs create a false impression for beginners that `Free` is a panacea to Destroy errors.

Comment: Delphi 2005 is one of the buggiest Delphi ever released - did you apply available updates, BTW? And I'm not sure if FastMM was already the default memory manager then  - you may need to download and add it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Before looking for leaks in code, you first need to understand if you really have a leak or not. Task Manager shows what Windows knows about your application, and its number needs to be understood in the context of how Windows manages memory - then you have to understand how Delphi manages memory within an application.

To learn how to read Task Manager numbers, I'd suggest you the excellent Mark Russinovich's blog and videos:

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2011/WCL405

He will explain you how actually memory allocation in Windows works (Delphi memory managers then suballocate it, but it still need to use Windows memory allocations calls), and will also explain many of his tools which allows to give a deeper look to many of the inner workings of Windows applications - beyond what FastMM can tell you.

There are also tools called "profilers" that can track memory allocation and deallocations and tell you which code allocates memory and later does't free it.

Otherwise you may chase leaks that actually don't exist...

Comment: It's an answer because first you need to understand what you really ask... it's perfectly useless to try to track a leak if you first don't understand what a leak is, and use wrong/incomplete informations to check for it. As Raymond Chen often explain, sometime you don't need to answer what someone asks for - you really to understand what he or she really need. In this case, before hunting down leaks in code, you need to explain the OP how to properly understand if he or she has a leak or not.

Comment: It should be a comment. Not all questions have an answer. This is one of them.

Comment: It has an answer: learn how to check properly for memory leaks, before believing to have one and waste your time asking someone how to slove a leak that maybe doesn't exist in the first place. This way you help someone to focus on what's is really important, while commenting on the use of Free/FreeAndNil in this context is pretty useless.

Comment: The only literal question here is if there's someone there (here?) who can explain a 4KB leak. "Yes, Mark Russinovich can explain it" may satisfy the question depending on if he's *there* or not.

Comment: Russinovich is there in the video and will explain you what the 4KB "leak" is. If you're too lazy to watch it and understand how Windows memory manager works and what Task Manager shows you really, and prefer to be just the usual clueless Delphi developer who always wonder at what happens outside its IDE because besides dropping controls on a form he has no understanding about how Windows really work, well, you're welcome... or you may spend some time learning about Windows and become a *true* Windows developer and not just a "component dropper and event writer". Your choice...